# WPF: How to bind the IsEnabled property of a button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, isenabled

With WPF how can I bind the `IsEnabled` property of a `Button` to the selected row's `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` value of my grid?

So every time the selected row of my grid changes the button will be enabled/disabled depending on the value of one of it's columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button would look something like this

```
<Button Content="Update" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=SelectedItem.SomeValue}"/>
```